# dummy variable encoding or one-hot encoding from Monday to Friday based on datetime with DolphinDB

Tags: one-hot-encoding, dolphindb

Monday to Friday are independent variables of the model, but in order to eliminate the effects of 1-5 base units, one-hot encoding or dummy variables need to be constructed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Through the dayOfWeek(), you can get what day of the week the current date is, and then judged by `iif`, you can construct a 5-column sparse matrix (one-hot encoding)

```
for(i in 1:6)
{
outputTable["DW"+i] = iif(outputTable.interval_date_time.dayOfWeek()==i,1,0)
}
```

[image]